# Safety of disabling unsafe-eval 2 seconds after page load, versus disallowing it from the start?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, eval, content-security-policy

**I'm currently working on a project which requires unsafe-eval at startup** due to the use of `lodash`'s `_.template` function. **After startup eval is no longer needed.**

**After load, I'm modifying disallowing `window.eval`** as below.

How does the security of the below compare with disallowing `unsafe-eval` in the site's CSP? Would it be safer to modify the CSP meta tag to add `unsafe-eval` after the initial load? **What kinds of attack vectors do both of these methods still leave open?**

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  window.eval = global.eval = function () {
    throw new Error(`Sorry, this app does not support window.eval().`);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That leaves open absolutely everything not doing at all would leave. Use precompiled templates: https://lodash.com/custom-builds Or skip Lodash templates entirely and use plain JavaScript, depending on the type of template.

Comment: Unfortunately the code which uses unsafe-eval is a dependency and is outside of my control. And of all the company's pushing this code, it's Google!

Can you please provide an answer elaborating on "leaves absolutely everything open" because certainly this is not the case. This leaves much less open than doing nothing, yet still a lot I'm sure.

Comment: It leaves the same amount open as doing nothing because there are lots of ways to `eval` that aren’t `window.eval` – in particular, the `Function` constructor, which is probably even more common than `eval` (I’d be surprised if `_.template` didn’t use it). The good news is that doing nothing is fine because `unsafe-eval` isn’t particularly dangerous.

Comment: If I instead modify the CSP to disallow `'unsafe-eval'` after 2 seconds, can you provide a specific example of a vulnerability?

Comment: Can you even do that with a CSP…? And can you provide an example of a specific vulnerability if you just leave `'unsafe-eval'` on?

Comment: You can modify the CSP from allowed sources and Chrome will honor the change, though I cannot guarantee all browsers will. Regarding providing a specific vulnerability, `unsafe-eval` is prefixed with `unsafe` for a reason. The site accepts user submitted content.

Comment: Are you using Angular without AOT compilation or something similar where templates end up in HTML? (Kendo?) If you enable a report-only CSP that’s the same minus `'unsafe-eval'` and you don’t get any reports, `'unsafe-eval'` off isn’t protecting you against anything, and I would advise against doing this weirdness that pretends to offer any protection (because the usual `'unsafe-eval'` suspects happen at page load, they don’t wait 2 seconds).

Comment: Can you possibly provide an example? I'm really looking for a specific example of a load-time vulnerability from allowing `unsafe-eval` in those two seconds.

Comment: I mean, pick any `unsafe-eval` example, and it *could* be at load time. `<div>{{ some user content }}</div>` on the server with a client-side template thing that evaluates the content after the fact. If you don’t have any user content in the initial page, you probably aren’t affected. (Again, can check with report-only.) I’d still figure out a way to use precompiled templates in the dependency, by the way, because it will end up as less of a hack than the 2-second thing.

Comment: I'm hoping Google will patch the issue since I've brought it to their attention, but I am just looking for a stopgap in this, and also just to extend my knowledge of the specifics of an `eval` based attack. Given the nature of my site, I think this is pretty safe, though of course not ideal. Hopefully Google will patch it quickly enough.

Comment: Which Google tool is it?

Comment: Firebase, astoundingly.